# Why is my sprite graphing algorithm sometimes leaving gaps while graphing?

Tags: javascript, css, html, canvas, html5-canvas

My friends and I are working on a game. However, I've run into difficulty with the star sprite management. Sometimes, there are gaps (areas where sprites should be graphed but instead are not). I have included the entire program as a code snippet but below are also code blocks which are likely directly responsible for the problem.

There are coordinate pairs for each sprite. The coordinate map is presented below:

```
[{x:xCoordinate,y:yCoordinate},{x:xCoordinate,y:yCoordinate},...];
```

This code spawns and removes sprites...

```
for(var i = 0; i < stars.positions.length; i++){
        //store coordinate positions...
        var x = stars.positions[i].x;
        var y = stars.positions[i].y;

        //delete sprites no longer visible within the viewport...
        if(x > window.innerWidth || x < -spriteWidth || y < -spriteHeight || y > window.innerHeight){
            //sprite is no longer visible within viewport; remove it...
            stars.positions.splice(i,1);
        }

        //find necessary comparative coordinates... 
        var lowestXCoordinatePair = stars.meta.lowestXCoordinatePair;
        var highestXCoordinatePair = stars.meta.highestXCoordinatePair;
        var lowestYCoordinatePair = stars.meta.lowestYCoordinatePair;
        var highestYCoordinatePair = stars.meta.highestYCoordinatePair;

        //gather star sprite meta data...
        var spriteWidth = stars.meta.spriteWidth;
        var spriteHeight = stars.meta.spriteHeight;

        if(lowestXCoordinatePair.x > 0){
            //Gap on the left side. New sprites necessary to fill the gap on left row...

            //console.log('adding sprites left row...')
            for(var i = 0; i < stars.meta.imagesYRequired; i++){
                stars.positions.push({
                    x:lowestXCoordinatePair.x-spriteWidth,
                    y:lowestXCoordinatePair.y+i*spriteHeight
                });
            }
        }

        if(highestXCoordinatePair.x < window.innerWidth-spriteWidth){
            //Gap on the right side. New sprites necessary to fill the gap on the right row...

            //console.log('adding sprites right row...')
            for(var i = 0; i < stars.meta.imagesYRequired; i++){
                stars.positions.push({
                    x:highestXCoordinatePair.x+spriteWidth,
                    y:highestXCoordinatePair.y+i*spriteHeight
                });
            }
        }

        if(lowestYCoordinatePair.y > 0){
            //Gap on the top side. New sprites necessary to fill the gap on the top row...

            //console.log('adding sprites top row...')
            for(var i = 0; i < stars.meta.imagesXRequired; i++){
                stars.positions.push({
                    x:lowestYCoordinatePair.x+i*spriteWidth,
                    y:lowestYCoordinatePair.y-spriteHeight
                });
            }
        }

        if(highestYCoordinatePair.y < window.innerHeight-spriteHeight){
            //Gap on the bottom side. New sprites necessary to fill the gap on the bottom row...

            console.log('adding sprites bottom row...')
            for(var i = 0; i < stars.meta.imagesXRequired; i++){
                stars.positions.push({
                    x:highestYCoordinatePair.x+i*spriteWidth,
                    y:highestYCoordinatePair.y+spriteHeight
                });
            }
        }
```

```js
'use strict';


//global variables
var canvas, c;

//viewport variables
var viewportPosition = {
 x:false,
 y:false
};

//game matrix settings
var gameMatrixConfig = {
 width:20000,
 height:20000
};

//cursor position
var cursorPosition = {
 x:false,
 y:false
};

//spaceship position
var spaceship = {
    x:false,
    y:false,
    rotation:0,
    gameMatrixPositionX:false,
    gameMatrixPositionY:false
};

//fps monitor (for monitoring frame rate for development purposes)...
var fps = {
    lastFrameTime:undefined,
    timeSinceLastFrame:undefined,
    startDisplayTimeInterval:function(){
        setInterval(function(){
            document.getElementById('fpsLabel').innerHTML = Math.floor(1000/getTimeSinceLastFrame());
        },500);
    }
};

function getTimeSinceLastFrame(){
    return fps.timeSinceLastFrame;
}


//resize throttle timer global variable holder
var resizeTimer = false;

//the drawing frame:
var renderFrame = false;

//global events
window.addEventListener('load',function(){
 initialize('load');
});

window.addEventListener('resize',function(){
 clearTimeout(resizeTimer);
 resizeTimer = setTimeout(function(){
  initialize('resize');
 },100);
});

window.addEventListener('mousemove',function(e){
 cursorPosition.x = e.clientX;
 cursorPosition.y = e.clientY;
});


//global functions
function initialize(type){
    if(type == 'load'){
        preLoadSprites();
    }
    initializeCanvas();
}

function initializeCanvas(){
 canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
 c = canvas.getContext('2d');
 canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
 canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
 c.width = canvas.width;
 c.height = canvas.height;
}

/*a class with a filePath argument.
This class is used to create new sprite images
from an instance of the class.*/
function sprite(filePath){
    //create a new image preload
    this.sprite = new Image();
    this.sprite.src = filePath;
    //load status
    this.loaded = false;
    /*
    holds all current positions of the sprite.
    default start coordinates are 0,0
    */
    
    this.positions = [];
    
    //original associative array data structure...
    //this.positions = {};
    
    
    //the image has been preloaded
    this.sprite.addEventListener('load',function(){
        this.loaded = true;
        /*
        bind the "this" reference of the constructor to avoid referencing
        the load event function
        */
    }.bind(this));
}

function preLoadSprites(){
    //create new objects for all the sprites to be used in the game
    var sprites = {
        stars:new sprite('https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=0B821h2dKD0r_bERZb0RHeVRTQnM')
    };
    
    /*
    check the load status of the sprites
    loop through all properties of sprites object twice per second
    check for load status. Load flag default is true. Set flag to false
    when an unloaded image is discovered.
    */
    var interval = setInterval(function(){
        var x, loaded = true;
        for(x in sprites){
            if(!sprites[x].loaded){
                loaded = false;
            }
        }
        if(loaded){
            clearInterval(interval);
            //complete other tasks such as hiding a load spinner...
            
            //ready sprites and context for graphing and provide access to sprites....
            initializeGraphing(sprites);
        }
    },50);
}

function initializeGraphing(sprites){
    //set initial viewport position in game matrix....
    viewportPosition.x = gameMatrixConfig.width/2;
    viewportPosition.y = gameMatrixConfig.height/2;
    
    //start graph animation loop; provide access to sprites....
    graph(sprites);
}

/*research how to inherit values from another object with
local variables.*/
function graph(sprites){
    updateSpritePositions(sprites);
    //testing frame rate...
    setInterval(function(){draw()},16.67);
    //60fps interval code. Uncomment when testing is complete...
    //setInterval(function(){draw()},16.67);
    
    //calculate sprite requirements for viewport and configure a sprite matrix...
    initializeStars(sprites.stars);
    
    fps.startDisplayTimeInterval();
    
    //render the graphic frame
    function draw(){
        //console.log(fps.timeSinceLastFrame)
        fps.timeSinceLastFrame = Date.now()-fps.lastFrameTime;
        //fps.displayTimeInterval();
        //fps.lastFrameTime = Date.now();
        
        //clear the canvas
        c.clearRect(0,0,window.innerWidth,window.innerHeight);
        //graph the stars...
        graphStars(sprites.stars);
        updateSpritePositions(sprites);
        fps.lastFrameTime = Date.now();
    }
}

function initializeStars(stars){
    /*
    calculate sprite requirements for viewport and configure a sprite matrix
    this only needs to happen once unless the viewport is resized
    */
    
    /*
    meta data used for various calculations throughout the script...
    */
    stars.meta = {
        //required sprites to fill the viewport width (based on sprite width)...
        imagesXRequired:Math.ceil(window.innerWidth/(stars.sprite.width))+2,
        //required sprites to fill the viewport height (based on sprite height)...
        imagesYRequired:Math.ceil(window.innerHeight/(stars.sprite.height))+2,
        //required sprites to fill the entire viewport...
        get requiredSprites(){
            return this.imagesXRequired*this.imagesYRequired;
        },
        //the sprite width...
        spriteWidth:stars.sprite.width,
        //the sprite height...
        spriteHeight:stars.sprite.height,
        //the lowest x value in stars.positions...
        get lowestXCoordinatePair(){
            var xCoordinates = [];
            var yCoordinates = [];
            for(var i = 0; i < stars.positions.length; i++){
                xCoordinates.push(stars.positions[i].x);
                yCoordinates.push(stars.positions[i].y);
            }
            var x = Math.min.apply(Math, xCoordinates);
            var index = xCoordinates.indexOf(x);
            var y = yCoordinates[index];

            return {
                x:x,
                y:y
            };
        },
        //the highest x value in stars.positions...
        get highestXCoordinatePair(){
            var xCoordinates = [];
            var yCoordinates = [];
            for(var i = 0; i < stars.positions.length; i++){
                xCoordinates.push(stars.positions[i].x);
                yCoordinates.push(stars.positions[i].y);
            }
            var x = Math.max.apply(Math, xCoordinates);
            var index = xCoordinates.indexOf(x);
            var y = yCoordinates[index];

            return {
                x:x,
                y:y
            };
        },
        //the lowest y value in stars.positions...
        get lowestYCoordinatePair(){
            var xCoordinates = [];
            var yCoordinates = [];
            for(var i = 0; i < stars.positions.length; i++){
                xCoordinates.push(stars.positions[i].x);
                yCoordinates.push(stars.positions[i].y);
            }
            var y = Math.min.apply(Math, yCoordinates);
            var index = yCoordinates.indexOf(y);
            var x = xCoordinates[index];

            return {
                x:x,
                y:y
            };
        },
        //the highest y value in stars.positions...
        get highestYCoordinatePair(){
            var xCoordinates = [];
            var yCoordinates = [];
            for(var i = 0; i < stars.positions.length; i++){
                xCoordinates.push(stars.positions[i].x);
                yCoordinates.push(stars.positions[i].y);
            }
            var y = Math.max.apply(Math, yCoordinates);
            var index = yCoordinates.indexOf(y);
            var x = xCoordinates[index];

            return {
                x:x,
                y:y
            };
        }
    };
    
    //the y coordinate in a scaled matrix system for sprites...
    var y = 0;
    //the x coordinate in a scaled matrix system for sprites...
    var x = 0;
    //loop through the number of required sprites and graph...
    for(var i = 0; i < stars.meta.requiredSprites; i++){      
        //calculate when a new row is necessary
        if((i)%stars.meta.imagesXRequired == 0){
            x = 0;
            y++;
        }
        
        //set actual starting viewport matrix coordinate positions....
        stars.positions[i] = {
            x:x*stars.meta.spriteWidth,
            y:y*stars.meta.spriteWidth
        };
        x++;
    }
}

function graphStars(stars){
    /*
    prior to graphing, determine if a sprite is no longer within
    the viewport matrix and remove it...
    
    if new sprites are necessary, add new coordinates accordingly...
    */
    
    
    
    /*
    ==============IMPORTANT NOTE==================
    
    */
    
    for(var i = 0; i < stars.positions.length; i++){
        //store coordinate positions...
        var x = stars.positions[i].x;
        var y = stars.positions[i].y;

        //delete sprites no longer visible within the viewport...
        if(x > window.innerWidth || x < -spriteWidth || y < -spriteHeight || y > window.innerHeight){
            //sprite is no longer visible within viewport; remove it...
            stars.positions.splice(i,1);
        }

        //find necessary comparative coordinates... 
        var lowestXCoordinatePair = stars.meta.lowestXCoordinatePair;
        var highestXCoordinatePair = stars.meta.highestXCoordinatePair;
        var lowestYCoordinatePair = stars.meta.lowestYCoordinatePair;
        var highestYCoordinatePair = stars.meta.highestYCoordinatePair;

        //gather star sprite meta data...
        var spriteWidth = stars.meta.spriteWidth;
        var spriteHeight = stars.meta.spriteHeight;

        if(lowestXCoordinatePair.x > 0){
            //Gap on the left side. New sprites necessary to fill the gap on left row...

            //console.log('adding sprites left row...')
            for(var i = 0; i < stars.meta.imagesYRequired; i++){
                stars.positions.push({
                    x:lowestXCoordinatePair.x-spriteWidth,
                    y:lowestXCoordinatePair.y+i*spriteHeight
                });
            }
        }

        if(highestXCoordinatePair.x < window.innerWidth-spriteWidth){
            //Gap on the right side. New sprites necessary to fill the gap on the right row...

            //console.log('adding sprites right row...')
            for(var i = 0; i < stars.meta.imagesYRequired; i++){
                stars.positions.push({
                    x:highestXCoordinatePair.x+spriteWidth,
                    y:highestXCoordinatePair.y+i*spriteHeight
                });
            }
        }

        if(lowestYCoordinatePair.y > 0){
            //Gap on the top side. New sprites necessary to fill the gap on the top row...

            //console.log('adding sprites top row...')
            for(var i = 0; i < stars.meta.imagesXRequired; i++){
                stars.positions.push({
                    x:lowestYCoordinatePair.x+i*spriteWidth,
                    y:lowestYCoordinatePair.y-spriteHeight
                });
            }
        }

        if(highestYCoordinatePair.y < window.innerHeight-spriteHeight){
            //Gap on the bottom side. New sprites necessary to fill the gap on the bottom row...

            console.log('adding sprites bottom row...')
            for(var i = 0; i < stars.meta.imagesXRequired; i++){
                stars.positions.push({
                    x:highestYCoordinatePair.x+i*spriteWidth,
                    y:highestYCoordinatePair.y+spriteHeight
                });
            }
        }

        c.drawImage(stars.sprite,x,y);
    }
}

function updateViewportPosition(){
    
}

function updateSpritePositions(sprites){
    
    /*gather information from the cursor to influence the next frame data
    cursor is a local object variable template for use within this function only
    cursor stores information about the cursor's position
    */
    
    var cursor = {
        distance:{
            //the cursor's distances on the planes from the origin for X and Y
            cursorXDistance:Math.abs(window.innerWidth/2-cursorPosition.x),
            cursorYDistance:Math.abs(window.innerHeight/2-cursorPosition.y)
        },
        quadrant:function(){
            //method returns the appropriate quadrant number for the unit circle
            if(cursorPosition.x > window.innerWidth/2 && cursorPosition.y < window.innerHeight/2){
                //first quadrant
                return 1;
            }
            if(cursorPosition.x > window.innerWidth/2 && cursorPosition.y > window.innerHeight/2){
                //fourth quadrant
                return 4;
            }
            if(cursorPosition.x < window.innerWidth/2 && cursorPosition.y < window.innerHeight/2){
                //second quadrant
                return 2;
            }
            if(cursorPosition.x < window.innerWidth/2 && cursorPosition.y > window.innerHeight/2){
                //third quadrant
                return 3;
            }
        }
    };
    
    //calculate the velocity (the number of pixels to move for the next frame)...
    function velocity(){
        /*
        To calculate velocity ratio, divide the hypotenuse of the cursor's position
        by the viewport hypotenuse.
        */        
        return Math.sqrt(Math.pow(cursor.distance.cursorXDistance,2) + Math.pow(cursor.distance.cursorYDistance,2))/100;
    }
    
    //calculate the movement ratio: the number of x pixels per y pixels
    function movementRatio(){
        var xRatio = cursor.distance.cursorXDistance/(cursor.distance.cursorYDistance+cursor.distance.cursorXDistance);
        var yRatio = cursor.distance.cursorYDistance/(cursor.distance.cursorYDistance+cursor.distance.cursorXDistance);
        return {xRatio,yRatio};
    }
    
    //update positions of sprites...
    
    //retrieve the current movement ratio object...
    var coordinateChange = movementRatio();
    //retrieve the current quadrant of the unit circle for the cursor's position...
    var quadrant = cursor.quadrant();
    //retrieve velocity coefficient...
    var velocity = velocity();
    //update viewport position based on quadrant position...
    
    var i;
    for(i in sprites.stars.positions){
        if(quadrant == 1){
            //update star sprite position
            sprites.stars.positions[i].x -= coordinateChange.xRatio*velocity;
            sprites.stars.positions[i].y += coordinateChange.yRatio*velocity;
        }
        if(quadrant == 2){
            //update star sprite position
            sprites.stars.positions[i].x += coordinateChange.xRatio*velocity;
            sprites.stars.positions[i].y += coordinateChange.yRatio*velocity;
        }
        if(quadrant == 3){
            //update the star sprite position
            sprites.stars.positions[i].x += coordinateChange.xRatio*velocity;
            sprites.stars.positions[i].y -= coordinateChange.yRatio*velocity;
        }
        if(quadrant == 4){
            //update star sprite position
            sprites.stars.positions[i].x -= coordinateChange.xRatio*velocity;
            sprites.stars.positions[i].y -= coordinateChange.yRatio*velocity;
        }
    }
}
```

```css
html,body{
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
}

canvas{
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
 margin-bottom:-8px;
 background:#434343;
}

#gameInterface{
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
}

.hidden{
 width:1px;
 height:1px;
 position:fixed;
 top:0;
 left:0;
 z-index:-100;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Canvas Game v0.35</title>
 <!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/index.css" type="text/css">-->
 <!--<script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>-->
</head>
<body>
    <div id="fpsLabel" style="position:fixed; top:0; left:0; display:table; background:#fff;">
    
    </div>
 <div id="intro">
 
 </div>
 <div id="gameInterface">
  <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I've brainstormed a list of possible causes for the problem:

- Gaps are caused by sprites being removed too soon.
- Gaps are caused by sprites not being spawned.
- (sub item) Spawning conditional is correct but the loop to create a new row is flawed.
- (sub item) Spawning conditional is flawed.

Could someone help me understand why there are occasionally gaps and help me understand how to fix it? Thank you.

Comment: I'm not seeing sprites (or anything) when I run the snippet.  There are some error messages in the console though.

Comment: @James Hmm, the sprite is stored in Google Drive. I'll check the URL and post another comment once I have it working. It worked in my browser since I am logged into Google Drive.

Comment: @James Thank you for notifying me. The problem has been fixed. Refresh the page and it should load the sprite.

Comment: I had a look at your working code.  It seems like when you add stars to, say, the bottom of the field it doesn't calculate that there is also a gap on the left that needs filled, probably you need to take into account (needs stars at bottom + needs stars on left) at the same time.  I wonder if it might be more efficient to have an image as your star field and move the image around rather than manually animating and keeping track of individual star objects.  Check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17171135/canvas-animating-a-simple-star-field)